# Notepad++ Regex - move string to inside a tag(s)

Tags: regex, notepad++

What I want to achieve is to write a *find and replace* regular expression to make this:

```
31927 31622 9
```

into tags in xml, for example:

```
<tag col1="31927" col2="31622" col3="9"></tag>
```

I've tried messing around with `.*?` - but I cannot get it to work. Can anyone point a beginner in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jT9wO9/1

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Press CTRL+F select the replace tab. Make sure search mode is marked with regex

Now on the  "Find what" type the regex:

```
(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)
```

on "Replace with" put your text referring to the groups like this:

```
<tag col1="\1" col2="\2" col3="\3">
```

Click on replace or replace all... 
your text:

> 31927 31622 9

should become

```
<tag col1="31927" col2="31622" col3="9">
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will try this, just to get the feeling of what I am doing. But I'm afraid the "31927 31622 9" is not unique. I have 10k Unique situations.

Comment: no problem :) if it worked you should make the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Like this you mean:

```
(?:["'])(\d+)(?:["'])
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jT9wO9/2)**

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Yes, something of the kind. But may I also ask how to apply this in the "replace-function" in notepad++? I have about 10k lines that I wish to convert.